# NgRx effects issue while fetching data (ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products'))

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have started learning NgRx framework in Angular. Getting below error while fetching the data from sample API.

*'ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'products')'*

I don't have feature modules. So, I have created a selector like this

```
export const selectProductState = createFeatureSelector<fromProduct.ProductState>(
    fromProduct.customerFeatureKey
);

export const getProductState = createSelector(
    selectProductState,
      (state: fromProduct.ProductState) => state
);
```

reducer code

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Product } from "../product";
import * as ProductAction from './product.actions';

export interface ProductState {
    products: Product[];
    error: string;
  }

  export const customerFeatureKey = 'products';
  
  export const initialState: ProductState = {
    products: [],
    error: ''
  };

  export const productReducer = createReducer<ProductState>(
    initialState,
    on(ProductAction.loadProductsSuccess, (state, action): ProductState => {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.products,
        error: ''
      };
    }),
    on(ProductAction.loadProductsFailure, (state, action): ProductState => {
      return {
        ...state,
        products: [],
        error: action.error
      };
    })
  );
```

effects code

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductEffects {

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private productService: ProductService) { }

  loadProducts$ = createEffect((): any => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ProductAction.loadProducts),
        mergeMap(()=> this.productService.getProducts().pipe(
            map(products => 
              ProductAction.loadProductsSuccess({products})
            )
        ))
    )
  })
}
```

I don't understand where am I doing mistake. Can anyone help me.

Comment: the only place in your code where this can be thrown is `products: action.products,` inside the `loadProductsSuccess`. Can you please do a console.log before the return statement to see what is inside the `action` object?

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved. In **app.module.ts** file

Replaced

```
StoreModule.forRoot(productReducer, {}),
```

with below code

```
StoreModule.forRoot({products:productReducer}),
```